# Memory layout for NV12 64x32 tile format?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, embedded-linux, gstreamer, yuv

can anyone explain memory layout for **NV12 64x32 tile** format like **NV12** format explained at this [link](https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-old/re36.html) (as follows).

**NV12 4 × 4 pixel image**

```
Byte Order. Each cell is one byte.
start + 0:  Y'00    Y'01    Y'02    Y'03
start + 4:  Y'10    Y'11    Y'12    Y'13
start + 8:  Y'20    Y'21    Y'22    Y'23
start + 12: Y'30    Y'31    Y'32    Y'33
start + 16: Cb00    Cr00    Cb01    Cr01
start + 20: Cb10    Cr10    Cb11    Cr11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NV12Tile format is explain on this [link](https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis-old/re36.html).

Additionally I have also solved conversion of NV12Tile to NV12 (or YUV420 Planner) format on this [link](https://github.com/ssshukla26/NV12Tile-To-NV12-Conversion).

Further more I have discussed same on gstreamer mailing list, you can refer the same on this [link](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Where-is-the-support-for-NV12-with-64x32-tiling-is-added-td4677225.html).